# Steam client GUI rendering glitch (flickering, weird overlay). Also affects Strife game

Tags: 14.04, graphics, games, steam, cache

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Macbook 2,1 with 4gb RAM (about 3gb usable). All other games run fine, but the Steam client itself renders all wonky, and Strife has the same problem as Steam.

Links and buttons all work properly when I click them, even when other graphics completely or partially cover them up because of the glitch. Images included below because it's hard to describe.

How do I fix this? I tried clearing the cache with

```
steam --reset
```

as recommended in a Steam troubleshooting article, but the terminal just returned "`Error: Couldn't find bootstrap, it's not safe to reset Steam. Please contact technical support.`"

I tried to look for appcache to clear it manually, but I can't find it in my files.

Strife gameplay screnshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOfsb.png

Steam library screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9K5q.png

Steam store screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zougp.png

Comment: Your two screenshots appear to be identical (they both show the Steam library screen as of 4:05 pm).

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. The Strife screenshot should be correct now.

Comment: I'm experiencing flickering with the Steam client but only while connected to the Steam Link, but not on my computer itself. The flickering is seen only on the Steam client but not during gameplay (at least for the few games I've tried)